# How to check if a document exists in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

IM trying to figuring out if a document exist . I wanna do that with the streambuilder to change methods if its exist. Heres how im trying

```
 StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection("videos")
                                      .doc(videos.data()['id'])
                                      .collection("uservotes")
                                      .doc(uid)
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, sasapshot) {
                                    if (sasapshot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    } else {
                                   
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
```

So the doc videos.data()['id'] is a video . The stream is wrapped with a stream and from there im gettin the curretn video . The current video can change because the 2 streams are wrapped with PageView.builder . Is what I want now is checking if these collection uservotes has the uid of the curretn user inside. so the uid. And on scrolling PageView I check that for each video . Hope thats clear. So my question is how can I do that ? Checking if the uid as document exist in uservotes subcolletion, with the stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exists` property.

```
if (snapshot.data.exists) {
//return logic if the document exists based on uid 
}
```